# Apache alias - Ignore alias for specific files

Tags: apache-2.4, alias

I'm currently working on a new project related to another one, the old one.
This old project let user uploads avatar, resulting on non-versionned files in `/images/avatars`.

But in the new project, I need these avatars files too. So I took the avatar directory and put it outside of projects and I use apache alias to serve files :

```
...
Alias "/images/avatars" "<path/to/shared>/images/avatars"
...
```

Just working fine.

But, the problem comes with the file `/images/avatars/default.png` which is actually the only one file to be versionned. And time to time the old-project team has to update it. So they commit it and push it on git, but when we asks git to pull it, that does what everyone expects from it : uploads the file in the original directory (`images/avatars/`) instead of the aliased directory. And so goes on, when we display `default.png` on web page, apache follows the alias and displays the copied version (so the old one).

Not sure how to fix that. What I would love to do is to say "Hey, Apache, lets follow this alias for all the avatars with just a litle tiny exception for default.png, would you ?". But life isn't that easy, is it ?

Answer (score 0):

And I finally found a solution. Instead of using "Alias" I should use "AliasMatch" like that :

```
...
AliasMatch "^/images/avatars((?!/default\.png).*)" "<path/to/shared>/images/avatars$1"
...
```

This part `((?!/default\.png).*)` is doing the magic. That captures all except if that match `default.png`.